# Почему работает?

Tags: c, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // int n; (Переменная не объявлена)
    int *n;

    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d",n); // (А здесь она используется)
    printf("Addr n is:  %p\n",&n);

    return 0;
}
```

Изучаю C. Почему работает код при том что переменная `n` используется в программе, но не была объявлена?

И правильно ли написана программа определения адреса?

Comment: А что вас смущает? Переменная по имени n, тип: указатель на целочисленное значение.

Comment: Здесь обычно спрашивают - "Почему не работает?"

Comment: Что значит "переменная не объявлена", если строкой ниже она у вас объявлена? В остальном: ваш код имеет неопределенное поведение. В указателе `n` содержится мусор и передавать его в `scanf` нельзя.

Answer (score 5):

**Случайно** мусор, находящийся в указателе `n`, имеет такое значение, что запись по этому адресу не приводит к сваливанию программы в строке

```
scanf("%d",n);
```

Ну, а все остальные строки совершенно нормальные...

И, кстати, переменная `n`, имеющая тип указателя на `int`, вполне объявлена (но не определена). Или вы считаете, что в

```
int * n;
```

`*` - это знак умножения? :)

Comment: Нет. Это именно указатель.

Comment: Ну вот, значит, переменная `n` объявлена - это к вопросу *"переменная n используется в программе, но не была объявлена"*.

Comment: Так... Переменная все-таки объявлена...Как получить ее адрес? И как получить адрес переменной
    {int n;}
?

Comment: @dimonbavly, «Как получить ее адрес?» — так же как и всегда: `&n`.

Comment: Адрес переменной получается операторам `&`. Вы же уже сами делаете это в своей программе. Откуда тогда вопрос?

Comment: @dimonbavly, смотрите: у вас нет переменной `n` типа `int`. У вас есть *переменная-указатель* (или просто *указатель*) `n`, который «указывает» на данные типа `int`.

Comment: @dimonbavly, советую прочитать [A Tutorial on Pointers and Arrays in C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Comment: Вот здесь - `printf("Addr n is:  %p\n",&n);` - вы вывели адрес именно переменной `n`. Т.е. адрес места в памяти, в котором хранится адрес некоторого `int`'а.